# In a Template Notebook how to make a Repeating Block loop over a local variable

Tags: notebooks, document-creation, templates

I have a template notebook that takes in some parameters to get raw data and then process it. In this processing a few subsets of data are calculated. However, I don't know how many subsets will be there when the template notebook parameters are selected.  From the processing in the template notebook I end up with a structure similar to the following:

```
results = {
 <|"a" -> "cage",  "b" -> "some stuff for cage"|>, 
 <|"a" -> "clamp", "b" -> "some stuff for clamp"|>, 
 <|"a" -> "net",   "b" -> "some stuff for net"|>}
```

Now what I would like to do is define a *Repeating Block* in the template notebook that loops over the variable `results` for a final bit of processing and display.  Keep in mind that `results` only exists in the template notebook; it is not a variable passed in through `GenerateDocument`.

I have tried typing the variable name `results` in each of the *Repeating Block* options and each time `GenerateDocument` is called it fails to recognise `results` and does not loop over it.

I need this is a *Repeating Block*.  I know I can map a function over `results` but I have other display elements and notebook formatting in multiple cells of the *Repeating Block* group.

Which option in the *Repeating Block* setup should I be using and what should I be typing in there to have it loop over `results`?

Comment: WRI has said that this functionality is not currently available but they are considering it.